# PL/SQL OUT SYS_REFCURSOR on associative array

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, associative-array

I have an associative array inside a procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE RET_STRING_TAB(o_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS

type type_ntz is record(type_id number, type_uname varchar(32), type_pwd varchar(16));

type ntz_array is table of type_ntz index by pls_Integer;

v_ntz_array ntz_array;

BEGIN 
Select id,uname,pwd BULK COLLECT INTO v_ntz_array FROM users;
```

As you can see i want to out a refcusor on that array, to work further in Java with it. I tried doing:

```
OPEN o_cursor FOR 
SELECT * FROM TABLE(v_ntz_array);
```

But it keeps saying:

- PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
- PL/SQL: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
- PLS: expression is of wrong type

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You TYPE needs to be create out of the procedure, so your calling program (ie: java) can access it and know it's composition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE type_ntz IS OBJECT(type_id number, type_uname varchar(32), type_pwd varchar(16));
/
```

then:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE RET_STRING_TAB(o_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS [...]
```

UPDATE

I've re-read your question and for me the easiest way to do what you are looking for is:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE RET_STRING_TAB(o_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
BEGIN 
    OPEN o_cursor FOR
    Select id,uname,pwd FROM users;
END;
/
```

Comment: Works! another question: the "bulk collect into" is throwing "not enough values". Am i using it correctly?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I don't think you need to create a TYPE for what you are trying to do.